# Save pdf on a particular location using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my C# Code :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + Session["pdf_name"] + ".pdf";
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        StringWriter s_tw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter h_textw = new HtmlTextWriter(s_tw);
        Label1.Style.Add("font-size", "16pt");
        Label2.Style.Add("font-size", "16pt");
        Label3.Style.Add("font-size", "16pt");
        h_textw.AddStyleAttribute("font-size", "8pt");
        h_textw.AddStyleAttribute("color", "Black");
        Panel1.RenderControl(h_textw);
        Document doc = new Document();
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, Response.OutputStream);
        doc.Open();
        StringReader s_tr = new StringReader(s_tw.ToString());
        HTMLWorker html_worker = new HTMLWorker(doc);
        html_worker.Parse(s_tr);
        doc.Close();
        Response.Write(doc);
}
```

I want to save this pdf in this Path "H:\new\web\pdf_filename.pdf"

I am using ASP.Net C#.

Comment: Want to save pdf file on server?

Comment: @HassanNisar yes website folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot specify where on the client machine the downloaded file will be saved.

If you want that type of functionality, you will need to run a plugin in the browser clientside that has access to the local file system.

The browser will take the filename you specify in your attachment header value as a suggestion, but even that can be overridden by the user when he actually saves it.

If you want to save it on the server, you only have to save it somewhere local (to the server) using any of the file-related methods or types.

Answer (score 0):

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(@"H:\new\web\pdf_filename.pdf", FileMode.Create));
```

try and see if this work, please make sure your authentication type is allow user to access that folder. Not everyone map H drive to same network path,

Comment: try replace your line
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, Response.OutputStream);

Comment: it gives an error "Could not find a part of the path 'H:\new\web\pdf_filename.pdf'."

Comment: had the folder being created ? and your web user have access on it?